# Rotating a div in clockwise direction using CSS animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am new to coding and trying to rotate a div element with id circle in the clockwise direction using CSS keyframe animation. Here is a sample of what I tried and it's not rotating

```
#circle{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color: white;
    animation: turn 10s infinite;
}
@keyframes turn{
    0%{
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    50%{
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    100%{
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Small question- you are setting the height and width and then the border radius at 50% to make the circle- but if you rotate a circle then you will not see it rotating cos it’s round. Are you sure it’s not working? Try taking off the border radius to get back to a square and it will be obvious if it is working

Comment: You are rotating a circle so it won't look like it is rotating. If you rmove the border-radius, you will see the animation.

Comment: Check out `transform-origin` if you don't want to rotate it around the point of the center of the circle. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Answer (score -1):

Try the code below

```
#circle{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color: white;
    animation: turn 10s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes turn{
    from{
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to{
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the above  code and it's still not rotating

Comment: thanks, all i removed the border radius as suggested and its's rotating